# Storing shapes in JComponent

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I am unsure of how to store multiple different shapes using one arraylist of type shape. Here is the main.

```
public class A1 {
public static boolean rDraw = false;
public static boolean eDraw = false;
public static boolean lDraw = false;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton rect = new JButton("Rectangle");
    rect.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource()==rect){
                rDraw = true;
                eDraw = false;
                lDraw = false;
            }
        }
    });
    JButton ellipse = new JButton("Ellipse");
    ellipse.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource()==ellipse){
                rDraw = false;
                eDraw = true;
                lDraw = false;      
            }
        }
    });
    JButton edge = new JButton("Edge");
    edge.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource() == edge){
                rDraw = false;
                eDraw = false;
                lDraw = true;       
            }
        }
    });
    JButton label = new JButton("Label");
    JTextField labelField = new JTextField(20);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(rect);
    panel.add(ellipse);
    panel.add(edge);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(labelField);
    frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JComponent canvas = new Canvas();
    frame.add(canvas,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setTitle("Graph Draw");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In my canvas, I am unsure of how to use drawShape? and what to put in the paintComponent to store the shapes.

```
public class Canvas extends JComponent {
private Point p,p2;
private Rectangle r;
private Ellipse2D ep;
private Line2D l;
ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

public Canvas(){
    class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener{
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if(A1.rDraw == true && A1.eDraw == false && A1.lDraw == false){
                p = e.getPoint();
                r = new Rectangle(p.x, p.y, p.x - p.x, p.y - p.y);  
            }
            else if (A1.rDraw == false && A1.eDraw == true && A1.lDraw == false){
                p = e.getPoint();
                ep = new Ellipse2D.Double(p.x, p.y, p.x - p.x, p.y - p.y);
            }
            else if (A1.rDraw == false && A1.eDraw == false && A1.lDraw == true){
                p = e.getPoint();
                l = new Line2D.Double(p.x, p.y, p.x - p.x, p.y - p.y);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if(A1.rDraw == true && A1.eDraw == false && A1.lDraw == false){
                if (r.width != 0 || r.height != 0)
                {
                    addRectangle(r);
                }

                r = null;
            }
            else if (A1.rDraw == false && A1.eDraw == true && A1.lDraw == false){
                if (ep.getWidth() != 0 || ep.getHeight() != 0){
                    addEllipse(ep);
                }
                ep = null;
            }
            else if (A1.rDraw == false && A1.eDraw == false && A1.lDraw == true){
                if (l.getP1() != null || l.getP2() != null){
                    addLine(l);
                }
                l = null;
            }
        }
    }
    class MyMouseMotionListener implements MouseMotionListener{
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if(A1.rDraw == true && A1.eDraw == false && A1.lDraw == false){
                int x = Math.min(p.x, e.getX());
                int y = Math.min(p.y, e.getY());
                int width = Math.abs(p.x - e.getX());
                int height = Math.abs(p.y - e.getY());
                r.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
                repaint();
            }
            else if (A1.rDraw == false && A1.eDraw == true && A1.lDraw == false){
                int x = Math.min(p.x, e.getX());
                int y = Math.min(p.y, e.getY());
                int width = Math.abs(p.x - e.getX());
                int height = Math.abs(p.y - e.getY());
                ep.setFrame(x, y, width, height);
                repaint();
            }
            else if (A1.rDraw == false && A1.eDraw == false && A1.lDraw == true){
                p2 = e.getPoint();
                l.setLine(p, p2);
                repaint();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
    MouseListener mListener = new MyMouseListener();
    addMouseListener(mListener);
    MouseMotionListener mmListener = new MyMouseMotionListener();
    addMouseMotionListener(mmListener);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (Shape shape:shapes){

    }
    if(A1.rDraw == true && A1.eDraw == false && A1.lDraw == false){
        g2d.draw(r);
    }
    else if (A1.rDraw == false && A1.eDraw == true && A1.lDraw == false){
        g2d.draw(ep);
    }
    else if (A1.rDraw == false && A1.eDraw == false && A1.lDraw == true){
        g2d.draw(l);
    }
}
public void addRectangle(Rectangle rect){
    if(r != null){
        Rectangle cR = new Rectangle(rect);
        shapes.add(cR);
        repaint();
    }
}
public void addEllipse(Ellipse2D ellipse){
    if (ep != null){
        Ellipse2D cEp = new Ellipse2D.Double(ellipse.getX(),ellipse.getY(),ellipse.getWidth(),ellipse.getHeight());
        shapes.add(cEp);
        repaint();
    }
}
public void addLine(Line2D line){
    if(l != null){
        Line2D cL = new Line2D.Double(line.getP1(), line.getP2());
        shapes.add(cL);
        repaint();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `"...and what to put in the paintComponent to store the shapes."` -- this shouldn't be part of the paintComponent method. This method is for drawing items on the component and nothing more. It should not be used for program logic. The code for storing shapes should be in your mouse listener type code, not in paintComponent.

Comment: Inside of your for loop in the paintComponent method, you should have `g2d.draw(shape);`.

Comment: All the code in the paintComponent method after the for loop should be eliminated.

Comment: Please see updates to answer.

Comment: Please don't deface your question by deleting code. Please understand that your question and the answers here are not for you per se, but rather are for the benefit of future visitors who might have similar problems. If you deface your question, all that benefit is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your paintComponent method appears to be doing too much and too little: too little in that it's not drawing Shapes, and too much in that it's trying to do things with the static boolean fields that it shouldn't.

> "...and what to put in the paintComponent to store the shapes."

this shouldn't be part of the paintComponent method. This method is for drawing items on the component and nothing more. It should not be used for program logic. The code for storing shapes should be in your mouse listener type code, not in paintComponent.

I think that all you need in paintComponent is simply this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (Shape shape : shapes) {
        g2d.draw(shape); // !! added
    }
}
```

As a couple of side notes:

- you've got much too much static code within your A1 class, including static fields, and most all of it should be instance code, and most of the code within the main method should be removed and placed into a constructor. The main method should be very small.
- You'll want to rename your Canvas class to something different as this creates a potential name clash with a core Java class, `java.awt.Canvas`, and might confuse others or even the compiler should you move this class to another package in the future.
- You can combine your MouseListener and MouseMotionListener code into a single class that extends MouseAdapter. This will simplify your code, and allow you to avoid posting empty method stops.
- Since your drawing selections are mutually exclusive, I would use JRadioButtons or JToggleButtons all held in a single ButtonGroup, so that the user can easily see what selection is currently active, and so that selection of one button turns off selection of all the others.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the storing works properly now; however, I no longer get the smooth drawing (while dragging the mouse around, I can't see the outline of the shape), as right now I just drag and a shape randomly appears. I followed your advice and fixed the naming. About the main class, I'm not sure what you mean by too much static code.

Comment: @JClutch: OK, then I was wrong, perhaps you do need the code after the for loop within paintComponent. Re static, the main method should be very small, a few lines perhaps, and its job should be to create your main classes (`new Something()`) and set it running. Most of the code that you currently have in the main method is code that builds up the GUI and shouldn't be in there.

Comment: @JClutch: and your storing always worked fine -- you just never used the Graphics2D object to draw what was stored. A simple fix. 1+ to your question -- I'm not sure why it was down-voted.

Comment: I added what I had previously after the loop and it works fine, but I now get a NullPointerException, can I just ignore it as everything works fine? About the main, I think I understand what you're saying. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JClutch: no, never ignore a NPE. The heuristic for NullPointerExceptions is almost always the same. **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: Ooooo ok, thanks for the tips. I got rid of the lines that made each shape null and that fixed it.

Comment: @JClutch: You're welcome. If I have time later, let me re-visit your code to show you possible changes.